# How did the Apollo astronauts train for the 1/6G lunar landing?

Tags: apollo-program, gravity, lunar-landing, training

It goes without saying that training/conditioning one's reflexes for a situation is highly relevant to some professions. Pilots train in a computer simulator.

During the [Apollo missions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Project) computers were not as ubiquitous as they now are. The [CSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Module#Command_Module_.28CM.29) could be, and was checked-out in Earth orbit.

The [Lunar Module (LM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module) however was meant for a non-Earth environment; one which could probably not be simulated - yet it would have been necessary to give the astronauts a 'feel' of the craft in reduced gravity.

The mission commander for [Apollo-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11) apparently did such a great job with his manual landing the [shock-absorbers failed to depress](http://www.popsci.com/military-aviation-amp-space/article/2009-06/40-years-later-ten-things-you-didnt-know-about-apollo-ii-moon-landing). This may be merely an urban legend ... but it does draw one's attention to the question -

How did the Apollo astronauts train to land the LM in the 1/6th lunar gravity?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

They used the [Lunar Landing Training Vehicle](http://history.nasa.gov/alsj/LLTV-952.html), as pictured below. This had a jet engine to provide 5/6 of the lift needed to hover the vehicle, plus rocket engines that simulated the LM's engines.
With the jet running, the LLTV felt like it weighed 1/6 of its actual weight, so it came pretty close to simulating moon gravity.

[image]

Comment: Truth in advertising: That thing looks just as dangerous as it actually was.

Comment: Rockets or jets for the 5/6 thrust?

Comment: Um, second sentence of my answer? " This had a jet engine to provide 5/6 of the lift"

Comment: @WayneConrad Well, I don't know. After all, it has an ejection seat, that is not immediately obvious. OTOH, it was deangerous enough to test the seat in action, so...